# Can i use old plugins when migrating to Struts2.3.32 from 2.3.16

Tags: plugins, struts2

Currently I have following struts files

> 1. struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar
> 2. struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar
> 3. struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar
> 4. struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar
> 5. struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar
> 6. struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar

Could I only only change to these:

> 1. struts2-core-2.3.32.jar (update to 2.3.32)
> 2. struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.32.jar (update to 2.3.32)
> 3. struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar (no change)
> 4. struts2-json-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar (no change)
> 5. struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar (no change)
> 6. struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar (no change)

Or I have to update all plugin to 2.3.32 ?

Comment: Maybe. I wouldn't. Why would you want to deliberately not use the right version?!

Comment: It very hard to have all plugins the same version many of them are deprecated.

Comment: Yes, if I change to new version, many problems happened.

Comment: Using `maven` dependencies prevents all this kind of troubles

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use that.